# Camera permission message when building Android app with expo:build

Tags: react-native, expo

When I test my app inside expo app everything works.

When I build a Android binary using `expo build:android` the camera and camera roll stop working. I get the permission message, I grant the access but nothing happens.

I'm using this code and always get 'granted'.

```
if (status === "granted") {
  let image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    mediaTypes: "Images",
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    base64: true
  }).catch(error => console.log(permissions, { error }));

  this.setState({ editPhoto: image.uri });

  ImageManipulator.manipulate(image.uri, [], {
    base64: true,
    compress: 0
  }).then(img => {
    ProfileStore.setBaseImage(img.base64);
  });
}
```

I’m using expo sdk 30.

Using the adb logcat, I found this line:

> 11-01 14:17:14.111 3019 3092 I ReactNativeJS: 'camera', { error: { [Error: User rejected permissions] framesToPop: 1, code: 'EUNSPECIFIED' } }

But, inside android Settings -> App -> My App all permissions are granted.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, the solution was remove all permissions from App.json.

Comment: You saved my life man, I had to deliver my app before the deadline today and I spent all day trying to solve this puzzle. The app now asks for ALL Expo permissions which is also bad but at least the camera works now... I'm hoping this will be solved in newer Expo versions